# Java - Generate JSON array

Tags: json

I am trying to generate a JSON in Java but not getting in the right format.
Expected output: `{"Fruits":"[Apple]","Color":"Red"}`

What i tried:

```
Set<String> fruits= new HashSet<>();
    fruits.add("Apple");


JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

JSONArray fruitsArray = new JSONArray();
fruitsArray.put(fruits);

json.put("Fruits", fruitsArray);
json.put("Color", "Red");

return json.toString();
```

But this results in : `{"Fruits":[["Apple"]],"attributes":"true"}`, an additional square brackets around Apple. How do i modify code to get to the actual result, the one without the additional square brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve your expected output, you would need to do the following:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("Fruits", "[Apple]");
    json.put("Color", "Red");
```

I believe what you wanted is actually an array of fruits, which should be represented as `{"Fruits":["Apple","Pear"],"Color":"Red"}` and can be achieved as follows:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray fruitsArray = new JSONArray();
    fruitsArray.put("Apple");
    fruitsArray.put("Pear");

    json.put("Fruits", fruitsArray);
    json.put("Color", "Red");
```